# mozilla extension - reading stdout of external process

Tags: xpcom, thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

I am trying to run `dvipng` process from a thunderbird extension using `Components.interfaces.nsIProcess`. I need to read standard output of the process, but I am not able to find a way to do that. I found some threads on `nsIProcess2`, but that one was (as it seems) never fully implemented with stdout. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`nsIProcess2`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/NsIProcess2) is unrelated - it *was* implemented but later folded into `nsIProcess`. It was only about starting processes asynchronously.

The relevant bugs are [bug 484246](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=484246) and [bug 68702](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=68702). The latter has been resolved but so far that code doesn't ship with Firefox/Thunderbird by default (it's quite a bit of code that neither Firefox nor Thunderbird need themselves). So your options are:

- Build IPCModule yourself and make it part of your extension - not recommendable because it will cause [lots of troubles](http://adblockplus.org/blog/binary-xpcom-components-are-dead-js-ctypes-is-the-way-to-go).
- Create a native library that will call `dvipng` for you, use it via [js-ctypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/js-ctypes) - should be the easiest solution.
- Turn `dvipng` into a library and use it directly via js-ctypes - probably not too hard either, this will also give you better performance.

Comment: I would like to build a thunderbird extension that will cross-platform if possible, without building additional libraries. Am I getting it right that in javascript itself (I am new to this language, sorry), there is no way to call a process while reading its standard output, or at least redirecting its standard output to file?

Comment: Yes, that's true unfortunately. You might get the "redirecting output to a file" part by calling the command line shell with the right parameters.

Comment: given what you say, how realistic is it to write an extension in python (my language of choice otherwise)? I know there is [PythonExt](http://code.google.com/p/pythonext), but I could not google up a single real extension coded in python.

Comment: I would recommend forgetting it. PyXPCOM is mostly abandoned and shipping it with your extension is lots of trouble.

Comment: I figured the easiest would be to have javascript spit out shell script (with all output redirection and so on, and writing needed stuff to output files) and run it using `nsIProcess`. Linux-only, but... good enough for now.